# What should I use to fill in a gap created behind cement boards after making the wall plumb?

Tags: drywall, walls, cement-board

Because I had to plumb a wall I had to sister the studs and that left me with two gaps in the corner like in the picture below. One corner is cement board(E) with existing cement board(D) , the other one is cement board(E) with existing drywall(D)
All the lumber is 2x4s:
D- existing drywall in one corner, the other similar corner has cement board
E -cement board that I am installing, not in place yet

A-existing stud
B-existing stud not plumb so I had to sister it using the stud C

Stud C is 3/8" off from B's inner edge

If I am installing E (cement board) as in the picture I will have two issues here:

1. no support for the corner edge of E; that edge will still be screwed to C.
2. there will be this empty space between the cement board that I do not know if it is OK to leave
   it there

What is the recommended way to deal with this?

[image]

Comment: I would just leave it alone. Once the corner of the drywall is adequately sealed, nothing shall be able to get into this space.

Comment: I was thinking about using mud or foam

Comment: Both are fine if the space is accessible after placing the last stud.

Comment: E is not there yet so yes the space is accessible

Comment: So no more problem then. Use the dry-pack that sticks better.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say dry pack?

Comment: A mortar with the least amount of water yet maintains the consistency of the mixes.

Comment: I am more inclined to use a foam spray here. Any issues with that ? Not sure how the foam behaves when humidity gets to it, especially in the corner where I have cement board meeting cement board (that is where the shower is)